# In command ogr2ogr add ogc_fid in output

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr

I am executing the command

```
ogr2ogr -nln "demodata" -lco GEOMETRY=AS_XY -t_srs EPSG:4326  -preserve_fid 
        -f "CSV" "/tmp/demo.csv" "PG:host=localhost dbname=demo user=root password=root schemas=public tables=demodata" "public.demodata"
```

I am getting all fields except FID (ogc_fid). That works for my requirements when I create shapefiles, and I don't want to change source elements. But for CSV file I also need the FID.

I tried to add the parameter to the command:

```
-addfields "ogc_fid"
```

In both cases I get:

```
ERROR 1: Field 'ogc_fid' not found in source layer.
```

Is there any way to force ogr2ogr to return FID no matter if it is in structure or not.

Comment: You can't force it to give you something that doesn't exist.

Comment: It exist in database, i was hoping it is enough for standard usage of ogr2ogr

Comment: does it not work if you get rid of the `-preseve_fid` parameter in your original command?